# AJAX loses "+" from email address string

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have some ajax code that seems to work fine for most of the places I've used it so far, however on trying to use it for a user details update on my page, it seems to lose the "+" symbol if used in an email address (such as `test+test@test.com` comes through as `test test@test.com` in my PHP file.

```
function prefUpdate() {
    let ytTog = document.getElementById("togBtn").checked;
    let unameNew = document.getElementById("uname").value;
    let usnameNew = document.getElementById("usname").value;
    let emailNew = document.getElementById("email").value;
    let params = "ytTog="+ytTog+"&unameNew="+unameNew+"&usnameNew="+usnameNew+"&emailNew="+emailNew;
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'pref_update.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            let return_data = xhr.responseText;
            if(return_data) {
               <do stuff>
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.send(params);
}
```

So here I grab a button, first and less name along with email address and pass it to a php file which returns some data that I can do stuff with.

I feel it could be the `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` that's causing it, but googling around that hasn't given me much of a way of resolving it.

[edit] just to say I tried `multipart/form-data` in place of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but this just broke things entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encode your data properly when making an ajax call.
You can use a URLSearchParams object to do this for you.

```
let params = new URLSearchParams({ytTog, unameNew, usnameNew, emailNew});
...
xhr.send(params);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right. For Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded all '+' signs mean ' ' (space). So it should be encoded by function `encodeURIComponent()`.

```
let params = Object.entries({ ytTog, unameNew, usnameNew, emailNew })
  .map(pair => pair.map(encodeURIComponent).join('='))
  .join('&');
```

Form [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

> For application/x-www-form-urlencoded, spaces are to be replaced by +, so one may wish to follow a encodeURIComponent() replacement with an additional replacement of %20 with +.

Comment: Thank you, I already tried @Musa's solution which worked, but thanks for responding aswell!

Comment: @Sam You're welcome

Comment: You have to call `encodeURIComponent` on each individual field value

Comment: Indeed. Will change. But of course URLSearchParams is much cleaner solution. I just wanted to show why it's happening with '+' signs

Comment: I will add some more boilerplate code just to keep my original answer, but in production use @Musa 's code